# Regex help, JS try to converting a string(html) to number

Tags: javascript, regex, regex-lookarounds

I've a string like this:

```
<span class="label label-danger">€ -185,00</span>
```

I try to convert to: -185,00 with js.

This is what I do:

```
x = x.replace(/[^\d\,-]/g, "");
x = parseFloat(x.replace(/,/, '.'));
```

It near to works but take the "-" of the class "label-danger" and all positive numbers become negative and negative become NaN (--185).

How to remove only the first "-" of the string with regex?

Comment: instead of throwing away any non-number chars, you could _select_ a string of chars that looks like a number. Say, [something like `/-?[\d,]+/`](http://rubular.com/r/FdyltYQEzU).

Comment: Where did this HTML-like string come from?

Comment: uhm... the regex code is perfect but I need to select the "non number" part.

Comment: @torazaburo is a datatable cell.

Comment: Then just pick out the value with something like `cell.textContent`, then strip off the euro sign.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you want to extract the number then you can use following snippet

```js
console.log('<span class="label label-danger">€ -185,00</span>'.match(/[-+]?\d+(?:,\d+)+/)[0]);
console.log('$  +1,23,400'.match(/[-+]?\d+(?:,\d+)+/)[0]);
```

**Output :**

```
-185,00
+1,23,400
```

Comment: Thanks. This is what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't like RegEx, you can use pure JS like :

```
var y = parseFloat(x.split("€")[1].split("<")[0]);
console.log(y); // -185
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<span(.*?)>([^\d]*)(-|\+){0,1}([-\d,]*)<\/span>



Group 3: (-|\+){0,1}: optional You get: `-`      
you get the sign here - or + or nothing(whic means plus)
Group 4.    ([-\d,]*) `185,00`
```

Comment: Why are you parsing HTML with regexp?

Comment: suppose a situation where i get  html text as string via curl or httpget in java., and need to extract value of specific segment, what do you suggest for that ? @torazaburo

Answer (score 0):

first get element using javascript DOM

```
var string = document.getElementsByClassName("label label-danger")innerHTML;
```

then use javascript `parseInt()` function to convert that string into integer

you can perform this task by creating a function doing all the stuff

Comment: Right idea, but there is no `getElementByClass`, only `getElementsByClassName`, which returns a list, so it's not something you can directly set the `innerHTML` of.

Comment: oops ...! sorry for mistake.

Comment: Still not exactly right...you need to take the first element in the list, or use `document.querySelector('label.label-danger')` or something.

Comment: Also, `parseInt` will fail on the leading euro sign.